# R - Condensing rows based on continuity of start and end timestamps

Tags: r, dataframe, timestamp

I have some IDs with timestamps that are exhibiting behavior that is out of my control. This is causing new rows for the same ID, but the end_time for the first row of a given ID matches the start_time of the next row for that same ID. An example looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "3"),
                 start_time = c("7/4/2020 10:06:27", "7/16/2020 07:16:44", "7/16/2020 07:20:32", "7/9/2020 03:27:37", "7/4/2020 02:01:49", "7/9/2020 00:00:00"),
                 end_time = c("7/16/2020 07:16:44", "7/16/2020 07:20:32", "7/25/2020 18:17:46", "7/21/2020 20:13:16", "7/5/2020 09:17:54", "7/11/2020 15:43:22"))
```

```
> df
id         start_time           end_time
1  1  7/4/2020 10:06:27 7/16/2020 07:16:44
2  1 7/16/2020 07:16:44 7/16/2020 07:20:32
3  1 7/16/2020 07:20:32 7/25/2020 18:17:46
4  2  7/9/2020 03:27:37 7/21/2020 20:13:16
5  3  7/4/2020 02:01:49  7/5/2020 09:17:54
6  3  7/9/2020 00:00:00 7/11/2020 15:43:22
```

But I want to 'stitch' together the timestamps for id = 1 (and other possible rows exhibiting this behavior) to for one distinct row like below. Note how the end_time and start_time entries for this id match up identically.

```
> df
  id        start_time           end_time
1  1 7/4/2020 10:06:27 7/25/2020 18:17:46
2  2 7/9/2020 03:27:37 7/21/2020 20:13:16
3  3 7/4/2020 02:01:49  7/5/2020 09:17:54
4  3 7/9/2020 00:00:00 7/11/2020 15:43:22
```

The entries for id = 3 are appropriate because the end_time for the first instance is instance from the start time of the second instance, so the desired behavior be for those rows to be unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dplyr solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(start_time, end_time), ~ as.POSIXct(., format = "%m/%d/%Y %T")) %>%
  arrange(id, start_time) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(start_time != dplyr::lag(end_time, default=end_time[1]))) %>%
  group_by(id, grp) %>%
  summarize(start_time = start_time[1], end_time = end_time[n()]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   id    start_time          end_time           
#   <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>             
# 1 1     2020-07-04 10:06:27 2020-07-25 18:17:46
# 2 2     2020-07-09 03:27:37 2020-07-21 20:13:16
# 3 3     2020-07-04 02:01:49 2020-07-05 09:17:54
# 4 3     2020-07-09 00:00:00 2020-07-11 15:43:22
```

**Edited** to add `as.POSIXct`. One comment was to make sure to sort by `start_time` to make sure that comparisons were good, but realize that since those were originally *strings*, that there was no guarantee that they would sort correctly. For instance, `sort(c("7/31/2020", "12/01/2020"))` sorts incorrectly. Unlikely given this data, but still a good safeguard.

Comment: I was working on something very similar :) I like to use `first(x)` and `last(x)` rather than `x[1]` and `x[n()]` but it works the same.

Comment: I've been trying to convince myself that the readability of `first(x)` over `x[1]` is worth the ever-so-slight overhead that it's introducing. The largest reason for me to start using `first` is that, like `seq_len`, it reacts intuitively (not in a frame) when given a vector of length 0. Thanks.

Comment: @r2evans that's fantastic, thank you! I realized after the fact that one little tweak I had to do was add an `arrange(start_time) %>%` because some this data is weird and the rows don't always flow like the example I gave.

Comment: Yes, that's a good precaution, I'll add it, thanks for the suggestion. However, since those aren't proper dates, it'll only be "safe" when all are the same month/year.